# In Chrome, Opera et al. PDF hyperlinks from word docs still need Ctrl-click (like Word) for Hyperlink to work

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word, opera

This has been driving me nuts for at least a year.  When viewing a PDF created in Word (save as menu, as PDF) the hyperlinks survive the transition and they work great in Internet Explorer with just a click.

HOWEVER, in Chrome, Opera and many others I assume, you MUST STILL PUSH Ctrl-Click (Control Key Click) just like you do in Word to have the hyperlinks work IN A SEPARATE WINDOW.  This is slightly annoying in Word BUT AT LEAST IT TELLS YOU TO PUSH THE CTRL KEY!

There is no warning in these other browsers.  In them, if you click on a hyperlink it take you to it but in the same tab -- you have to remember to push the back button or you are lost.  If you use sophisticated PDF controls such as www.YourSite.com/SomeDoc.pdf#page=20 (to jump to page 20 in the other pdf), you jump within the document you are viewing.  For example, if you clicked on my example while viewing YourDoc.pdf on one of these rouge browsers, you'd jump to page 20 in YourDoc.pdf not to SomeDoc.pdf, page 20.

If you're viewing in Adobe on your computer, you are OK.  I can no longer get adobe to load into any browser.  This may have been how this started: the other browser companies decided to get cute and force you to use their internal browser or they'd make you use adobe outside the browser.

If anybody knows how to integrate this new DC Reader into a web browser like in the "old days," I'd like to know how to do it.

I hope this helps some people.

Comment: When reading a PDF in a browser, having links open in the very same tab is exactly the expected behaviour, I feel. It's not different from viewing a web site in your browser. So, if Internet Explorer is opening links in a new tab/window, then I'd say *that* browser is behaving badly.

Comment: 1) What @Arjan said. 2) Please tone down the rant a bit - this is not a case of browser companies deciding to "get cute" or forcing you to do anything; if anything, it's a case of them trying to make things convenient. 3) If you don't like how your PDF viewer works inside the browser, just disable the relevant plugins and the PDFs should be saved to your downloads folder instead of being opened in the browser, then open the downloaded file in your viewer. 4) Please look up "rouge" and "rogue" in a dictionary... there's a difference. ;-)